# Conditions for existence of a solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-modeling

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windkessel_effect
So I'm doing a mini research project (TIPE) for french entrance exams. And I came across this blood flow modelization which involves some differential equations like:
${\displaystyle (1+{R_{1} \over R_{2}})I(t)+(R_{1}C+{L \over R_{2}}){dI(t) \over dt}+LC{d^{2}I(t) \over dt^{2}}={P(t) \over R_{2}}+C{dP(t) \over dt}}$

My questions are: could I actually solve this equation (assuming I have sufficient initial conditions) without having another equation that relates $P(t)$ to $I(t)$? Do solutions for this kind of equation even exist? If yes, is it analytically solvable?
N.B: I don't know much about differential equations except the basic ones like linear first order equations and linear second order equations with constant coefficients and zero for right-hand side.
I appreciate any help :)

Comment: You need to know how $P$ relates to $I$ for sure.

Comment: The question *could I find a solution* has a trivial answer - yes, you can. $I(t)=0$ and $P(t)=0$ are an example. But I'm pretty sure this is not the solution you're interested in.

Comment: Assuming the R,C, and L are constants, there might be a solution that you get by the method of variation of parameters [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters).

Comment: Ok so let's assume I know $P(t)$ take this periodic form (the blue graph):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windkessel_effect#/media/File:Cardiac_cycle_pressure_only.png
Can I now solve for $I(t)$ ?